# Expand one column while preserving another

Tags: text, awk

I am trying to get column one repeated for every value in column two which needs to be on a new line.

cat ToExpand.txt

```
Pete    horse;cat;dog
Claire  car
John    house;garden
```

My first attempt:

cat expand.awk

```
BEGIN {
        FS="\t"
        RS=";"
}
{
        print $1 "\t" $2
}
```

awk -f expand.awk ToExpand.txt

```
Pete    horse
cat
dog
Claire  car
John
garden
```

The desired output is:

```
Pete    horse
Pete    cat
Pete    dog
Claire  car
John    house
John    garden
```

Am I on the right track here or would you use another approach? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also change the `FS` value into a regex and do something like this:

```
awk -F"\t|;" -v OFS="\t" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $i}' ToExpand.txt
Pete    horse
Pete    cat
Pete    dog
Claire  car
John    house
John    garden
```

I'm assuming that:

- The first tab is the delimiter for the name
- There's only one tab delimiter - If tab delimited data occurs after the `;` section use fedorqui's implementation.

It's using an alternate form of setting the `OFS` value ( using the -v flag ) and loops over the fields after the first to print the expected output.

You can think of `RS` in your example as making "lines" out of your data ( records really ) and your print block is acting on those "lines"(records) instead of the normal newline.  Then each record is further parsed by your `FS`.  That's why you get the output from your first attempt.  You can explore that by printing out the value of `NF` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk '{gsub(/;/,ORS $1 OFS)}1' OFS='\t' file
```

This replaces every occurrence of a semicolon with a newline, the first field and the output field separator..

Output:

```
Pete    horse
Pete    cat
Pete    dog
Claire  car
John    house
John    garden
```